# Web Api Pdf download and routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So i trying to lean web Api and implement in my project.

There are two things that i am not quite sure about

1. I am trying to download pdf. My web api is in App Server and i am consuming it in my web server.

In my web api I have a method in controller

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{        
    [ActionName("GetFile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string FileName, string CEQRNumber, string LatestMileStone)
    {
        var file = GetListofFilesByCEQRAndMilestone(FileName, CEQRNumber, LatestMileStone);
        var path = file.FilePath;
        var extension = file.FileExtention;
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

        if (extension == ".pdf")
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        if (extension == ".xlsx" || extension == ".xls")
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        if (extension == ".zip")
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("aapplication/zip");

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now i am not sure how to consume it. In my main mvc app in web server. I have an action method

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string fileName, string ceqrNum, string latestMS, string token)
{
    string url = "https://xxx/api/Files/GetFile/" + fileName + "/" + ceqrNum + "/" + latestMS;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf"));

            Task<String> response = client.GetStringAsync(url);

            // NOT SURE HOW TO CONVERT RESPONSE TO PDF

        }
}
```

1. The second question i have is in routing: In webApiConfig.cs there is a default route set up

   ```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
   ```

I noticed that if i have to have diffrent parameters I have to add that in config

so I added

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetFileList",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{CEQRNumber}/{LatestMileStone}",
            defaults: new
            {
                CEQRNumber = UrlParameter.Optional,
                LatestMileStone = UrlParameter.Optional,
            }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetFileForDownload",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{FileName}/{CEQRNumber}/{LatestMileStone}",
            defaults: new
            {
                Controller = "Files",
                FileName = UrlParameter.Optional,
                CEQRNumber = UrlParameter.Optional,
                LatestMileStone = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Now, can i have one default route that will work irrespective of parameters and action name or with every different action and parameters I have to write new route.

I will appreciate your answers. I am trying to understand the concepts of web api as this is the first time i am using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments -

1. Don't open the file as read/write, read is plenty good.
2. The second route is fine you don't need the first one, you can alternatively just post to the following route:

`api/{controller}/{FileName}/{CEQRNumber}/{LatestMileStone}`

and remove the `[ActionName]` attribute from the GetFiles.

Even simpler you can use the following route
`api/{controller}` and pass the parameters as a query string.

so it's going to look like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

Your url is going to look like:

```
http://xxx/api/Files?FileName=foo&CEQRNumber=bar,&LatestMileStone
```

The controller code:

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{        
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string FileName, string CEQRNumber, string LatestMileStone)
    {
        var file = GetListofFilesByCEQRAndMilestone(FileName, CEQRNumber, LatestMileStone);
        var path = file.FilePath;
        var extension = file.FileExtention;
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

        // do the header work
        return result;
    }
}
```

For your client code instead of ReadAsStringAsync use

```
 using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
 {
     // Read response stream
     await ReadResponseStreamAsync(responseStream, fileName);
 }
```

and don't forget to validate the response code on the client

For your comment on how to save a file from a stream:

```
 private void ReadResponseStreamAsync(stream responseStream, string fileName)
 {
      using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Path\\To\\" + fileName))
      {
            responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
      }
 }
```

Comment: I wanted to know how the client code looks like. I already have the api controller method that works perfectly.  Can you please elaborate on how the client will work. I am sorry if i was not clear on the second question I wanted to know do i have to change or add values in config.Routes.MapHttpRoute depending on diffrent parameter in different Action.

Comment: Basically what I wrote in the last code section gets you a response stream. Take that stream and write it to a file, or whatever storage want to get it to. I added a small sample at the end.

Comment: When it come to routes, my point was that you do not necessarily have to add extra routes, and use query parameters instead. Is that something you want to avoid? Your alternative to providing per method route parameters is just to use attribute routing. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2. Here is also a link to a ton of WebApi samples with attribute routing highlighted: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/WebApiAttributeRoutingSample/Readme.txt

Comment: I am not trying to avoid query parameter. It just that when i was using query parameter I would always get an error with "?" and "&". I don't remember the error exactly but it was like having "?" and "&" in the query string was being considered as a threat.

Comment: I just don't understand how this Task/await/async works. Is there any article that explain me how that works. When using async the return type is Task<Object>. If I am using complex object it gets confusing. Example .Say Employee object has List<Department>. List of Deptartment comes form web api as Task<List<Department>> and rest of Employee object values comes from non web api sources. I don't understand how i can parse Task<List<Department>> to List<Department> to put every thing together and display the object of Employee on my view

Comment: This is really a topic for another question :) To quickly get you going - just await the result of the async Task<List<Department>> method if you are in an async method yourself. `await YourAsyncMethod` or if you are in a sync method `YourAsyncMethod().Result`. If you have to use .Result a lot something is wrong with how you set up your code.

Here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx